# Fibonacci practice, fixing a Name Error even though the rest of my code works

Tags: python

The Fibonacci sequence begins with 0 and then 1 follows. All subsequent values are the sum of the previous two, ex: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13. Complete the fibonacci() function, which has an index n as parameter and returns the nth value in the sequence. Any negative index values should return -1.

Ex: If the input is:

```
7
```

the output is:

```
fibonacci(7) is 13
```

Note: Use a for loop and DO NOT use recursion.

```
def fibonacci(n):
   a = 0
   b = 1
   for i in range(1,n):
      global c
      c = a + b
      a = b
      b = c

   return c



if __name__ == '__main__':
     start_num = int(input())
     print(f'fibonacci({start_num}) is {fibonacci(start_num)}')
```

so far im getting the correct numbers and i have yet to add the -1 issue, but my main problem rn is that the code is saying that when i input 0 or -1 it tells me "name 'c' is not defined"

Comment: Because you only define `c` inside the loop, but with `0` or `-1`, the loop is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the variable "c" is defined as global down in the "for" loop, but that coupled with the fact that the for loop would not be executed for any negative number entry probably is the cause of the undefined behavior and error you got.  With that in mind, it seems to make sense to just add a value test for the input parameter of the function and if it is less than zero, return a value of "-1" before even attempting to execute the "for" loop.

With that in mind, following is a refactored version of the code.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 1                       # Define the result variable here

    if (n < 0):                 # Specifically return -1 for any entry of a negative number
        return -1

    print("0  ", end="")        # Starting number is "0"

    for i in range(1,n):
        print(c, " ", end="")   # Start printing Fibonacci values beginning with "0 + 1"
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c

    print(c, " ")               # Print final value 
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
     start_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
     print(f'fibonacci({start_num}) is {fibonacci(start_num)}')
```

The things to note are:

- The variable "c" is defined with the other variables and given an initial value of "1" to start the sequence.
- If the input parameter for the function is less than zero, the function immediately returns a value of "-1" as indicated in your requirements.
- If the value is positive, the accumulation sequence is performed; and for illustration purposes, each derived value is printed.

Following were some tests of the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Fibonacci$ python3 NumberList.py 
Enter a number: 7
0  1  1  2  3  5  8  13  
fibonacci(7) is 13
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Fibonacci$ python3 NumberList.py 
Enter a number: -1
fibonacci(-1) is -1
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Fibonacci$ python3 NumberList.py 
Enter a number: -33
fibonacci(-33) is -1
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Fibonacci$ python3 NumberList.py 
Enter a number: 10
0  1  1  2  3  5  8  13  21  34  55  
fibonacci(10) is 55
```

Sometimes a simple value test will avoid instances such as undefined information.  As always, you may want to refer to further python tutorials on the use of loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(n):
global c
c = 0
a = 0
b = 1

for i in range(1,n):
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c

if n < 0:
    c = -1
return c
```

ended up just doing this to get it to work, thank you to the people who tried

Comment: There is no reason to use `global` for `c`.  This is a common beginner mistake on Python of not understanding how `global` works.  Python can always *read* any variable defined in an enclosing scope if the var_name isn't in use in the local scope, but if you try to write to the variable, it will write to the local scope instead.  `global var_name` tells Python that any assignments to `var_name` in the current scope should *write to the global namespace* instead of the local one.  `nonlocal` is used to write to an enclosing non-global scope.

Comment: i had used it because earlier it kept giving me "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment", and I had looked something up that said to use global and it ended up working so I left it there. thank you for the explanation, ill be sure to fix it

Comment: You were getting the UnboundLocal Error because you were always calling `return c`, but c was only defined if the loop ran at least once.